# How can I make a localstorage value in JavaScript into a serverstorage value?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, local-storage

I'm trying to create a project which involves users being able to vote, and taking or adding to a global bank of points.

This is my very basic prototype, but I need to find a way to have the localstorage value be global, and the same for every user, using serverstorage.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript variable testing</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks;

    function onClick() {
      clicks = +clicks + 1;
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // set the value to localStorage
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 500000; // get the value from localStorage
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
  <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You will need `serverStorage` for that....

Comment: Local storage is, well... *local*. It's right there in the name. If you want all users of your web page to see the same values you need to save to the server.

Comment: Is your project entirely client side(javascript) or is there any back end  involved ?

Answer (score 2):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is meant for storing data in the **User's Browser**. You might need to store data into your Server for your requirement. You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) for the same.